# How do I make the bot not leave a telegram group?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I created a new Telegram group, and my problem is that I cannot add any bot to it, knowing that I have created a channel and have linked it to the group and the bot is added to the channel with no problems. Please help me in adding the bot
[bot exit messages from My group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aJH7.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are anonymous in group and it looks like the bot you are trying to add doesn't supports anonymous admins.

Comment: Can I make the bot supports anonymous admins?

Comment: you can check bot api documentation https://core.telegram.org/bots/api. All the actions supported by bot are given here.

Comment: I made the admin anonymous to the unknown and this helped me connect external bots that I don't own, but the bot I created when I added it gets out of the group automatically

Comment: Sorry, I didn't got you. Is the admin anonymous now?

Comment: It was before and now it has been modified

Comment: same problem, it seems that if a channel has a human admin and a bot admin, when the human interacts (adding a member or posting a message) the bot leavs